# Vb.net - Getting time from website

Tags: vb.net, time

`"41:25"` is a time and it's constant changing.

```
<div class="game-time">
<span class="elapsed j-elapsed" data-game-time="1419174626">41:25</span>
```

I tried this but not worked:

```
 Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    For Each h As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("span")
        If Not Object.ReferenceEquals(h.GetAttribute("className"), Nothing) AndAlso h.GetAttribute("className").Equals("elapsed j-elapsed") Then
            Label6.Text = h.InnerHtml
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I also tried this code:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim theElementCollection9 As HtmlElementCollection = Nothing
    theElementCollection9 = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div")
    For Each curElement9 As HtmlElement In theElementCollection9
        If InStr(curElement9.GetAttribute("className").ToString, "game-time") Then
            Label6.Text = curElement9.InnerText
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I need an answer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a moment to review this *carefully*: [Ask]  `this not worked` is not very helpful

Comment: You need to read up on server side vs. client side controls.

Comment: i need an answer with some example codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken straight out of [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp)

Add this code and you should be on your way.

```
var myVar=setInterval(function(){myTimer()},1000);
function myTimer(){
var d = new Date();
document.getElementById("myTimeElement").innerHTML = d.toLocaleTimeString();
}
```

This will update the time each second. Also you may want to go look at [This link about asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) as Plutonix suggested.